# IdHttp отправка файла и параметров одновременно

Tags: c++, c++builder, idhttp

Не получается отправить на сервер POST-запрос с отправлением файла и параметров одновременно. Вся проблема в том, что параметры должны находиться в другом параметре, т.е. по типу

```
{ "общийпараметр":{"параметр1":значение1,"параметр2":значение2}}
```

Посмотрел про `multipart/form-data`, понял примерную отправку

```
std::auto_ptr<TIdMultiPartFormDataStream>PostData(new TIdMultiPartFormDataStream);
PostData->AddFile("file", filepath);
PostData->AddFormField("sometext", stringtext);
IdHTTP3->Post("https://www.example.com", PostData.get());
```

Но так и не понял, как несколько параметров встроить в другой параметр. Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос отпал, методом проб и ошибок получилось так:

```
String params = "{\"параметр1\":\"значение1\",\"параметр2\":\"значение2\"}";
TStringStream *stream = new TStringStream(UTF8Encode(params));
PostData->AddFormField("общийпараметр","application/json","utf-8",stream);
```